# Преобразование класса к типу double С++

Tags: c++, преобразование-типов

[image: Объявление моего класса]

Мне нужно написать преобразование моего класса к типу double. Возможно ли это сделать без использования оператора преобразования, как я сделала изначально?

Comment: Для каких именно целей Вам нужно преобразование матрицы в double?

Comment: А чем плох `operator double`?

Comment: по заданию университетскому нельзя использовать его к сожалению

Comment: Ответ: нет, нельзя сделать.

Comment: @LexMarchenko преобразование из матрицы в переменную типа double (вычисление среднего арифметического элементов матрицы)

Comment: @Margo, а функции для этого можно использовать у Вас в университете? Вам ведь по идее просто нужно получить значение, с которым в дальнейшем что-то будет происходить?

Comment: @LexMarchenko ну функцию и надо видимо, только я не знаю как именно сделать так, чтобы было именно преобразование

Comment: @LexMarchenko  чтобы в main было вот так написано:  double y=matrix2;

Comment: @Margo, если нужно именно в таком виде `double y=matrix2;` получить запись, то без операторов здесь не обойтись. Но в таком случае странно, что Вам запретили использовать их в университете. Можно увидеть, что требует само задание и что там написано про ограничения?

Comment: @LexMarchenko в самом задании и даже в примерах через оператор. просто преподаватель, который принимает задание, вводит свои неожиданные требования

Comment: К сожалению очень часто происходит одновременно два события: и преподаватели обычно некомпетентны в программировании, и студенты потом неправильно пересказывают что им сказали. Смею предположить, что вас просят создать внутри класса функцию `double get_avr() const {...}`, которая потом будет вызвана как `double y = matrix2.get_avr();` Угадал?

Comment: Может быть от Вас хотят такую запись: `y = static_cast<double>(matrix2);` ?? Ну то есть `explicit operator double()`? Ещё один вариант получается, пример:   [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/3c24k)

Comment: И вот ещё с конструкторами добавочка: [ссылка](http://cpp.sh/852k3).